# problems with c++ casting

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, casting

Hello I have three classes

1. AbstSoccerTeam
2. PlayersSoccerTeam
3. PlayersFieldPlayerStates

PlayerSoccerTeam is a child class of AbstSoccerTeam.

```
bool AlanSoccerTeam::isClosestTeamMemberToSupportingPlayer(FieldPlayer* plyr)
```

is a method in player soccer team.

i am trying to call that method in the PlayersFieldPlayerStates class with this

```
PlayersSoccerTeam* sTeam;
sTeam->isClosestTeamMemberToSupportingPlayer(player);
```

I can get this problem when i run it

uninitialized local variable 'sTeam' used

I dont know whats going on or why i am getting this error.

Any help is apprecitated greatly
Thanking You

Comment: It means exactly what it says; you have a variable `sTeam` and you try to use it without initializing it. If you don't understand why that's a problem ask yourself 'which team _should_ `sTeam` represent?' and 'which team _does_ `sTeam` represent? (and why/how does it represent that team?)'

Answer (score 1):

```
PlayersSoccerTeam* sTeam;
```

This line declares a pointer to a `PlayersSoccerTeam` and nothing else. All you get from this line is a pointer. It doesn't point anywhere in particular since you haven't initialized. There is no `PlayersSoccerTeam` anywhere to point to.

If you want an object of type `PlayersSoccerTeam`, then you just want:

```
PlayersSoccerTeam sTeam;
sTeam.isClosestTeamMemberToSupportingPlayer(player);
```

Since you told us about your hierarchy, it's possible that you want to use your `PlayersSoccerTeam` polymorphically as a `AbstSoccerTeam`. In this case you would need to use either a pointer or reference. This could be done like so:

```
AbstSoccerTeam* sTeam = new PlayersSoccerTeam();
// ...
delete sTeam;
```

Note that this still declares just a pointer, but the expression `new PlayersSoccerTeam` also creates a `PlayersSoccerTeam` object for the pointer to point to. Note that it's perfectly fine to assign a pointer to a `PlayersSoccerTeam` to a pointer to its parent `AbstSoccerTeam` - this is polymorphism in action. If you do this, you must make sure you `delete sTeam;` later, otherwise the object will be leaked.

A safer way to handle the user of dynamically allocated objects is to use a smart pointer, which you could do like so:

```
std::unique_ptr<AbstSoccerTeam> sTeam(new PlayersSoccerTeam());
```

Now you will not have to `delete` it because the `std::unique_ptr` takes care of that for you.

Comment: And an even more safer [sic] way would be using a `make_unique`...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you have created a pointer to a PlayersSoccerTeam but you have not actually created the object itself yet.

I would suggest doing this.

```
PlayersSoccerTeam sTeam;
sTeam.isClosestTeamMemberToSupportingPlayer(player);
```

You could alternatively do this.

```
PlayersSoccerTeam* sTeam = new PlayersSoccerTeam()
sTeam->isClosestTeamMemberToSupportingPlayer(player);
```

As perhaps an interesting education experience create a constructor that prints something to stdout when it is run and then try doing these two options and yours to see what happens.  A constructor will be run whenever a new object is created.